# Can I create axis labels with vertical-reading text with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I would like to create a plot like in the picture: the x-axis labels should be vertical, with the characters STACKED on top of each other.

I am aware of the rotating function, but I was wondering if this is possible as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str_replace_all`:

```r
str_vert <- function(x) str_replace_all(x, paste0("(.{1})"), "\\1\n")
```

example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble(name = c("AAA", "BBB"), value = c(0.3, 0.2))
str_vert <- function(x) str_replace_all(x, paste0("(.{1})"), "\\1\n")

ggplot(data, aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(label = str_vert)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  name = c("AAA", "BBB"),
  value = c(0.3, 0.2)
)

str_stack <- function(x) {
  x %>% str_split("") %>% map(~ .x %>% paste(collapse = "\n"))
}

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_discrete(label = str_stack)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: you got my upvote, but it would still be nice to have one or two words for less "knowing" people what you have done here.